# ec2 instance create fails using IAM role with terraform

Tags: amazon-ec2, terraform, amazon-iam

I am using terraform to create EC2 instance using IAM profile. With all the proper roles and policies set, I am still getting  the error:

> UnauthorizedOperation: You are not authorized to perform this  operation.status code: 403

Here is my main.tf:

```
provider "aws" {
  region = "us-west-2"
}

resource "aws_instance" "aws_test" {
  ami = "ami-image"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
  iam_instance_profile = "test-role"
}
```

Here is my aws policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "ec2:InstanceType": [
                        "t2.micro"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "iam:PassRole",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

This is the arn of role which I am using in my main.tf

> arn:aws:iam:::role/test-role

On googling, I found articles which tell me this should work, but I seem to be missing something. Any help would be highly appreciated. 
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Are you sure the access denied error is related to the iam_instance_profile?

Comment: the error says Unauthorised operation which does imply the role has no proper permission, isn't it?
the confusing part is the policy attached to that role has all the right permissions

Comment: It's saying that the user running Terraform doesn't have the correct permissions. Is that the full extent of the error? What permissions does the user/role that's executing that Terraform have?

Comment: the error only says this much, I have also attached the policy in the policy the said role is using, which seems to give all the required permissions

Comment: No, not the permissions you are giving the instance but the permissions you have on the user/role you are using to run Terraform.

Comment: ok apologies if I sound naive here, but I did not think any other permission was needed to run the terraform, does iam_instance_profile not fulfil that?

Comment: update: I am running this by directly installing terraform on an ec2 machine, not sure if this could be causing a problem

Comment: To use the AWS API you obviously need some credentials to identify yourself and those should have the necessary permissions to do things in AWS. It's probably worth going away and reading about IAM and/or taking some introduction to AWS type course before going too much further here.

Comment: @Akshay if you're running this directly on an EC2 instance, you're probably using the instance role of the EC2 machine to authenticate to AWS. I'd check the instance role permissions

Answer (score 1):

> update: I am running this by directly installing terraform on an ec2 machine, not sure if this could be causing a problem

Running the Terraform in the EC2 instance without providing the specific credential will [potentially use the Metadata API to retrieve credential](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/index.html#ec2-role).

You can check if you can call the Metadata API inside the instance.

Answer (score 0):

The `UnauthorizedOperation` means that the user or role running `terraform` does not have the permissions to make an `aws_instance`.

Make sure that the user or role running `terraform` has the proper permissions in AWS IAM